# htaccess Map One Directory To Another One Level Up

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

So here’s what I’m trying to accomplish. I have this link:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/
```

Now, the directory "foo" actually has a site in it that is up and operational. For the sake of organization I have had to create another site like this:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/
```

So in reality the link `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/` isn’t really a directory with anything it. What I would rather like to happen is when people go to `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/` that this address doesn’t change in the address bar, but rather on the backend the software actually brings up and uses `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/`.

**EXAMPLE:**

When someone goes to `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/sign_up.php` they still see this in their address bar, but what they're actually getting is `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/sign_up.php`.

**What I've tried so far to no avail:**

htaccess at `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*) ../fubar/$1 [NC,L]
```

Also

```
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^bar/(.*)$ RewriteRule ^.*$ ../fubar/%1 [L]
```

htaccess at `https://www.mydomain.com/`

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/(.*) /fubar/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** The directory `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/` is actually the root directory for `https://www.anotherdomain.com/`. So `https://www.anotherdomain.com/bar` should be bringing up `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/`

Comment: The last one is what you are looking for. But the leading `/` before `fubar` seems wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t do things like have `../` parent directory references like that for rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*) ../fubar/$1 [NC,L]
```

What you need to do is set something like this in the `.htaccess` of your site’s root on `https://www.mydomain.com/`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?(.*)$ fubar/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The last line basically grabs any URL that has `foo/bar` in it’s path, the `/?` makes the trailing slash optional, and the `(.*)$` captures the values passed as parameters.

Now, not 100% sure on my [addition of `QSA` (Query String Append)](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) to the rewrite rule flags, but the idea is the query string values get fully passed to the destination when you use. Which I assume  you would need, but if you don’t just use this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?(.*)$ fubar/$1 [NC,L]
```

Also, there is a nice way to debug rules like this without reloading the browser all of the time which can be a headache & cause issues when content is cached. And that is to temporarilly add the `R` (Rewrite) flag & use `curl -I` to view response headers directly while debugging.

For example, on my local MAMP (Mac OS X LAMP) setup I see this when I run `curl -I` to `http://localhost:8888/foo/bar/` with the `R` flag set:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8888/foo/bar/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 23 Jun 2014 14:11:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Location: http://localhost:8888/fubar/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

As you can see the `Location` changes to `Location: http://localhost:8888/fubar/` when using the `R` flag. Which is what you want. Then when you are done tweaking your rules, just remove the `R` flag & you should be good to go.

**EDIT:** Since the original poster states this desired behavior in their update to the question, a rewrite rule will never work:

> The directory `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/` is actually the root
>   directory for `https://www.anotherdomain.com/`. So
>   `https://www.anotherdomain.com/bar` should be bringing up
>   `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/`.

For a case like this, [`mod_rewrite`](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) is the wrong tool for the job. Use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead. First enable it in Apache like this; example assumes you are on Ubuntu 12.04 but should work on most any Linux Apache install

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Then set this to enable a reverse proxy on `https://www.anotherdomain.com` from your path of `/bar/` to `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/`:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  # Proxy specific settings
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /bar/ https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/
  ProxyPassReverse /bar/ https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/

</IfModule>
```

Comment: QSA is not needed here, because you are not modifying the query string. Example would be `RewriteRule ^foo/bar/?(.*)$ fubar/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]` then QSA is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working either. I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but didn't think about it. The directory `https://www.mydomain.com/foo/` is actually the root directory for `https://www.anotherdomain.com/`. So `https://www.anotherdomain.com/bar` should be bringing up `https://www.mydomain.com/fubar/`. Not sure if that helps or not.